# What is the openlayer.js alternative of unloadinvisibletiles of leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, leaflet, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers with a tile server. I want to load maps while panning and destroy the loaded region when out of screen (alternative to unloadinvisibletiles of leaflet.js)

How am I suppose to achieve this?

Comment: please stop crossposting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567589/what-is-the-openlayer-js-alternative-of-unloadinvisibletiles-of-leaflet-js